# c++ emplace_back with nested objects optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, c++14

I was slightly confused about behavior of emplace_back.
Let's have a look.

```
struct innerObject
{
    innerObject(int );
};

class outterObject
{
    innerObject member;
public:
    outterObject(innerObject member);
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<outterObject> v1;
    v1.emplace_back(5);
}
```

So in this case we could pass integer and it works.

What about constructor if `innerObject` needed *two* `int`s to construct from instead of just one? Neither `v1.emplace_back(5,5)` nor `v1.emplace_back({5,5})` nor any other combination which I tried works. Is it somehow possible? Is there any better option to make such things? (optimized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to avoid any kind of copy/move is for the outer type to opt-in to that sort of operation by providing a generalized constructor:

```
template <typename A0, typename... Args,
    std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<A0>, outterObject> &&
        std::is_constructible_v<outterObject, A0, Args...>
        , int> = 0>
outterObject(A0&& a0, Args&&... args)
    : member(std::forward<A0>(a0), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
{ }
```

This would let you write `v1.emplace_back(10, 20)` if `innerObject` were constructible from 2 `int`s.

If that seems like too much overkill, you can always just do `v1.push_back({{10, 20}})`. Note that `push_back()`, unlike `emplace_back()`, doesn't deduce its argument type - it's just `T const&` or `T&&`. This allows you to use `{}`s.

Comment: Thanks, so what will be the best option considering: 1) `v1.push_back({{10, 20}}) 2) innerMember`; `v1.emplace_back(innerMember) 3) innerMember`; `v1.emplace_back(std::move(innerMember))` ?
What I see is that push_back is the worst option here.
With std::move we use much more move constructor (instead of copy) than without. So I would go with `v1.emplace_back(std::move(innerMember))` because move is often cheaper.

Comment: In order to avoid the ugly `enable_if_t` i suggest go with tag-based approach and use something like `in_place`  from C++17 to disambiguate between copy constructor and member initializing constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works for one argument is that the single int constructor for your innerObject class acts as a converting constructor. In other words outterObject constructor takes an innerObject object, and due to the converting constructor rules, it converts the single int argument to an innerObject.

> A constructor that is not declared with the specifier explicit and
>   which can be called *with a single parameter* (until C++11) is called a
>   converting constructor.  [Link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor)

Converting constructors only work for single argument constructors.

If you write explicit before the innerObject constructor taking a single int, you'll see it won't compile, because "explicit" keyword disallows the int argument to automatically create an innerObject to pass to the outerObject constructor:

```
  v1.emplace_back(5); // v1 is a vector of outerObject.
```

The only reason this works is that the 5 argument is converted into an innerObject via its non-explicit constructor taking an int. This converting constructor behaviour only works for single argument constructors.

If you want you can add the two argument constructor to innerObject:

```
innerObject(int x, int y)
    {
        std::cout << "constructor innerObject" << std::endl;
    }
```

And then:

```
v1.emplace_back(innerObject(5, 6));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply construct inner object and than emplace_back:

```
v1.emplace_back(innerObject{10, 20});
```

Alternatively, you can add a constructor for `outerObject` which accepts two arguments and than calls `innerObject` constructor. In this case you would call it this way:

```
v1.emplace_back(10, 20);
```

Comment: @JesperJuhl your comment there was not correct. I first succumbed to it, and made edit, but I was in a hurry and didn't think straight. I rolled my answer back. My version with `innerObject` explicit constructor is sematically equivalent to original OP's example with a single integer argument. In both ways, you first call `inner` constructor with int argument, followed by constructor for outer (moving from inner).